# Site.com: How does one discard unpublished page changes?

Tags: salesforce

I have made some changes to a page within Salesforce's Site.com platform. I never published these changes, and now I want to discard them. Is there a way to do this? It seems basic enough, but I can't find any documentation implying such a functionality exists in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With discard do you mean to delete or rollback to older version?

For delete, I think we would need to manually delete each of the components like pages and assets(JavaScript/CSS/Images) from Site.com.

Comment: I meant rollback to an older version. For instance, I have an already published page, but we have unpublished changes to it that I'd like to get rid of.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I am afraid if that's possible, I used to take manual backup of the versions while making changes. As I didn't knew on how to rollback.